# How to make a change in a branch that has been changed in the latest version

Tags: git, azure-devops, devops

Say I have 2 branches, v1.0 and v2.0 which both correspond to the same project but one older version and one newer version. I am currently working on v2.0 with my team and a bug came up on v1.0 and we need to fix it, but the bug happened on a feature that has since been changed in v2.0 (v1.0 has been deployed to live servers and we need to fix it and re-deploy it to the live version since v2.0 is a project still in work).

How can we fix the issue on our v1.0 branch and merge it to our main branch for publish without getting merge conflicts from the previous changes from our v2.0 publishes to our test server.

Comment: There are lots of possible ways, but the one I prefer (when possible) is what's described in [Raymond Chen's blog articles](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180323-01/?p=98325). Basically you use the ability to "go back in time" to go back to the point where the bug was first introduced, *fix it there*, then *merge* the fix into all later releases where it's relevant.

Comment: @torek But would I be able to to push back to the branch? Would I be fixing it from the times I changed it or directly I fix it and push it to my branch?

Comment: Once you use the `git checkout release-branch; git merge fix` sequence, you have a *new commit that adds to* the release branch. Adding new commits to the tip of a branch is by definition how Git works and is trivial to `git push` since, well, that's how Git works. Note that each `git merge` operation done here adds a *different merge commit* (assuming different branch tip commits).

Answer (score 0):

One possible way could be - go to branch v1.0, fix the bug , merge it to your main branch, go to branch v2.0, rebase your branch with master. There are other ways though.

Comment: So if I rebase a branch with my master branch, will it replace all files in the master branch with the files in the branch I am rebasing? Or will they be overriden?

Comment: rebase will automatically take the commits in your current working branch and apply them to the head of the passed branch. As you are rebasing with the main branch, the changes in V2.0 will override the main branch, not replace all files. You might have to force push after rebasing